# Find minimum level in group and combine

Tags: javascript

In my application similar levels are grouped into an array, I need to fetch the minimum level in that group and replace with that minimum level in all the object. I couldn't get the desired result.

**Input**

```
let results =  [ [{LEVEL:2,NAME:"ADAMS"},{LEVEL:3,NAME:"JAMES"}],
                 [{LEVEL:4,NAME:"SHYAM"}],
                 [{LEVEL:6,NAME:"JIM"},{LEVEL:7,NAME:"ARUN"}]
                ]
```

**Output**

```
 output =  [{LEVEL:2,NAME:"ADAMS"},
            {LEVEL:2,NAME:"JAMES"},
            {LEVEL:4,NAME:"SHYAM"} ,   
            {LEVEL:6,NAME:"JIM"},
            {LEVEL:6,NAME:"ARUN"}
           ]
```

**Code**

```
result = results.reduce((r, a) => {

a.forEach(({LEVEL,NAME}) => {
        var min = r.find(q => q.LEVEL > LEVEL);
        if (!min) r.push({LEVEL,NAME});

});
return r;
}, []);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to do with `reduce` and `forEach` combination then I guess you can do as follows:

```js
const names = [
  [ {LEVEL:2,NAME:"ADAMS"}, {LEVEL:3,NAME:"JAMES"} ],
  [ {LEVEL:4,NAME:"SHYAM"} ],
  [ {LEVEL:6,NAME:"JIM"}, {LEVEL:7,NAME:"ARUN"} ],
];

const result = names.reduce((accumulator, elem) => {
  elem.forEach(e => {
    const smallestNumber = Math.min.apply( Math, elem.map(a => a.LEVEL) );
    accumulator.push({LEVEL: smallestNumber, NAME: e.NAME});
  });
    
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Iterate with `Array.flatMap()`, and map each sub array items into the minimum `LEVEL` value.

You can use `Array.map()` to get an arrays of `LEVEL`, and then spread them in `Math.min()` to get the minimum value (see the `getMinLevel()` function).

```js
const results = [[{LEVEL:2,NAME:"ADAMS"},{LEVEL:3,NAME:"JAMES"}],[{LEVEL:4,NAME:"SHYAM"}],[{LEVEL:6,NAME:"JIM"},{LEVEL:7,NAME:"ARUN"}]]
                
const getMinLevel = arr => Math.min(...arr.map(o => o.LEVEL))

const result = results.flatMap(arr => {
  const LEVEL = getMinLevel(arr)

  return arr.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    LEVEL
  }))
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

For each group, you're going to have to loop through twice. Once to find the min `LEVEL`, and then again to apply that min. I've used the [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) function here to iterate through these arrays, and I've used a bit of shorthand as well. `(group[0] || {LEVEL: 0})` checks if `0` is a valid index of `group`, and , if not, just uses a default object with a `LEVEL` of `0` to avoid errors. `min > result.LEVEL ? result.LEVEL : min;` checks if `min` is greater than `result.LEVEL`. If so, it yields `result.LEVEL`. Otherwise, it yields the current `min`.

```js
let results = [
  [{LEVEL: 2, NAME: "ADAMS"}, {LEVEL: 3, NAME: "JAMES"}],
  [{LEVEL: 4, NAME: "SHYAM"}],
  [{LEVEL: 6, NAME: "JIM"}, {LEVEL: 7, NAME: "ARUN"}]
];

results.forEach((group) => {
  var min = (group[0] || {LEVEL: 0}).LEVEL;
  group.forEach((result) => {min = min > result.LEVEL ? result.LEVEL : min;});
  group.forEach((result) => {result.LEVEL = min;});
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: It's always best to explain your answer, not just provide code. Otherwise the OP won't necessarily learn anything.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was in the process of writing the explanation while you commented that. Please check the updated answer.